# How to resolve 'getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN' error when launching Docker containers on WSL? docker launched with 'sudo dockerd --iptables=false'

Tags: angular, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, iptables, internet-connection

Docker containers on WSL not connected to the internet when launched with "sudo dockerd --iptables=false".
"npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/rxjs/-/rxjs-6.6.7.tgz failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org"

I am facing connectivity issues with Docker containers on Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) when I launch Docker using the command "sudo dockerd --iptables=false". Specifically, I am trying to run an Angular project, and during the "npm install" step, I encounter the following error: "npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/rxjs/-/rxjs-6.6.7.tgz failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org".

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

# Install node_modules
RUN npm install 

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080

# Run the project
CMD [ "npm", "run", "start-dev" ]
```

And my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
    frontend:
        build:
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            context: .
        container_name: frontend
        ports:
            - 8083:8080
        volumes:
            - /usr/src/app/node_modules
            - ./:/usr/src/app
        environment:
            - DEV_HOST=0.0.0.0
```

When I launch the project using sudo docker compose up --build, the containers start successfully. However, during the "npm install" step, I encounter the aforementioned error related to connectivity with the npm registry (https://registry.npmjs.org).

I have noticed that this issue occurs when launching Docker with the command "sudo dockerd --iptables=false". Is there a known reason why Docker containers on WSL might not have internet connectivity under these conditions? How can I resolve this issue and ensure that my Docker containers can access the internet properly?

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: do you mean I run it inside the container?

Comment: Can you run `curl https://www.google.com` inside container to check internet connection ?

Comment: because from wsl works fine, but from inside the container doesn't work